# App crash after installing firebase google service

Tags: flutter

I've been working on a app on VS and everything was working fine until i added firebase google service. When i try to open the app on VS emulator, it won't open and  show the following errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':wakelock'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

     If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.
```

this is name space value that i have:

```
namespace "com.example.app"
```

I've looked for same issues posted in this thred with no luck. Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.